# Fill Matrix with a for loop in r not working

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I'm using R for the following code.
I'm trying to fill the matrix s using a for loop as given below. My output is not coming as expected, in-fact none of the elements are being filled. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
N<- 3
S<- 2
delta = T / N
u = 2
d = 1 / u
s<- matrix(NA,N+1,N+1, byrow = TRUE)
s[1,1]<- S

for(i in 2:N+1){
  for(j in 1:i-1){
    s[i,j] <- (s[i-1,j]*u)
  }
    s[i,j] <- (s[i-1,j-1]*d)
}

s

My output
> s
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few parentheses in your for definitions. Which is indeed a bit confusing

```
 for(i in 2:(N+1)){
   for(j in 1:(i-1)){
```

there seems to be more wrong but I'm not sure about the intention of your code. Basically after the inner loop `j` will evaluate to zero which will index in

```
s[i,j] <- (s[i-1,j-1]*d)
```

the non-existing element `0`

Comment: If OP can add more to the question about what needs to happen at each step it will be easier to help. Currently as @CAFEBABE said its very difficult to see what the desired outcome is.